# How to use andOperator inside orOperator

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a function

```
Criteria[] regexBuilder(String field, String[] patterns) {
    return Arrays.stream(keyWordPattern)
            .map(it -> Criteria.where(field).regex(Pattern.compile(it, Pattern.LITERAL).toString(), "si"))
            .toArray(Criteria[]::new);
}
```

That I use like so:

```
// Assume type: String and keywords: String[]
Criteria.where("type").is(type).andOperator(regexBuilder("description", keywords));
```

What I want is to search for a match if the `description` field has **all** the keywords **or** the `notes` field has **all** the keywords. Something like:

```
Criteria.where("type").is(type).orOperator(
    andOperator(regexBuilder("description", keywords)),
    andOperator(regexBuilder("notes", keywords)),
);
```

How would I construct such a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like below.

```
Criteria.where("type").is(type).orOperator(
    new Criteria().andOperator(regexBuilder("description", keywords)),
    new Criteria().andOperator(regexBuilder("notes", keywords)),
);
```